# How do Muslims explain the similarities between the Epic of Gilgamesh and the story of Adam and Eve

Tags: adam-and-eve

I got confused because both of the Stories have striking similarities i would like an explanation?

Comment: This really is a lazy question. What is the basis on which one could answer were is the information needed to answer?

Answer (score 5):

Islam mostly just explains itself, it doesn't delve much into the history of previous nations, religions, cultures or anything except where it is relevant to Islam.

But one basic idea in Islam is that Allah has been sending prophets to every nation and every culture throughout history, way more than the handful that are explicitly named in the Qur'an. So it is a common speculation that any ideals or concepts similar to those found in Islam that are taught in other cultures were originally taught and passed down by long-forgotten prophets. And that any differences are due to corruption after being retold and reinterpreted over time while the exact original message was forgotten.

However, what most of these previous prophets taught, and to who, is not explicitly stated anywhere so that's merely speculation. It could always just be coincidence; if two independent and unrelated sources are describing the same event there are bound to be similarities. Allah knows best.

Comment: This seems reasonable, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is not only the story of Gilgamish, alot of stories actually, and not only stories, but even forms of worshipping (pilgrimage, fasting, praying, etc..) .. these have a lot of similarities with all other religions and cultures, the reason is in this hadith, where prophet mohamed peace be upon him is telling about almighty god: " And I created all my slaves hanifs (primitives and monotheists) and then the devils came and took them off their correct religion) ... thus originally the people since adam where monotheists and had the same correct beleif then they started going left and right, changing changing and changing their beleifs, language , culture and everything, however each other culture and religion is still having some relations with the original religion (monotheism / islam) in someway